# SQL Add a column that provides total count of current rows customer number

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, querying

I have a table like:

```
 KEY    CUST#     WAREHOUSE    ERRORMESSAGE  
 1      111       OH           Carton Error
 2      222       KY           Ship Error
 3      111       OH           Ship Error
 4      111       KY           Ship Error
 5      333       KY           Invalid Customer
```

And I would like to add a column that provides the total amount of rows with that same customer number. So for our example table, we would have:

```
  KEY    CUST#     WAREHOUSE    ERRORMESSAGE       CUSTCOUNT
  1      111       OH           Carton Error       3
  2      222       KY           Ship Error         1
  3      111       OH           Ship Error         3
  4      111       KY           Ship Error         3
  5      333       KY           Invalid Customer   1
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to make this happen? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: what RDBMS and version are you using? (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgresql, etc)

Comment: @Lamak I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [CUST#]) CUSTCOUNT
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is good design, as you would have to update every time you insert a row. Instead you should use it in your query.

Comment: Ok, would the select look different in query rather than adding the field to the table? Thank you very much.

Comment: Lamak wrote the correct query, but don't use it in your table. If you have a front-end use that query and put the values in the correct fields